# Why I'm getting gesture recognizers cannot be used on prototype objects?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm getting the above error from storyboard when I dropped a UITapGestureRecognizer inside a UIView which is inside a UITableViewCell in my scene.

Any idea why I'm getting this error ?

Comment: Probably because you can't! What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make one action when user taps on that view to make a change in the color of another view with animation inside the cell itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason myself. storyboard only allows that when we have a UITableViewController or it's subclass and the tableview content should be 'static cells' instead of default 'Dynamic Prototypes'. In that configures I can add a gesture recognizer inside the cell subview.

But that is a limitation and will not work in my case as I have a very customized view controller subclass instead of table view controller subclass. Need to find other way around it seems :(

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why the restriction is in place but I know why you are getting it the error.

When you design a `UITableViewCell` in StoryBoard you are only designing a prototype object.  i.e. the object may never actually exist.  It only gets ACTUALLY created in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

What might be a better approach is to create the gestureRecognizer when you configure the cell in code. This way you won't have this restriction.

I'd also possibly look at whether you actually need it? If it is just for a single tap with one finger then you may be better off coding the `touchesEnded` or just using a UIButton instead.

Comment: I can always write some code in the cell subclass to achieve it and that's I ways do where I can not use storyboard. The purpose is to write less code and configure the action from storyboard itself. Just wondering what wrong I'm doing there or why it's not allowed even though segue and gestures are available in storyboard. It can be a limitation but I'm not sure until the reason confirmed.

Comment: GestureRecognizers are allowed in storyboard... for objects that are not prototypes. You can add a gestureRecognizer to a UIView a UILabel anything. These are not prototypes as they are created (instantiated) by the storyboard. However, if they are inside a UITableViewCell then they become prototypes because they may never exist at all. They are created by triggering code that you write yourself.

Comment: We can add gesture recognizer in cell in storyboard, but that needs to be of 'static cell' content type in the table view. Please see my answer for details.